# Resize Sprites for CCAnimation

Tags: animation, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

I use some png sprites for my CCAnimation:

```
self.heroAnim = [CCAnimation animation];

for(int i = 1; i <= count; ++i) {
         [self.heroAnim addFrameWithFilename:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%d_%d.png", _spriteName, currentLevel, i]];
}

self.walkAction = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCAnimate  actionWithAnimation:self.heroAnim restoreOriginalFrame:NO]];
```

but now I have to change scale of CCAnimation (about size*0.75) Can you get me some suggestion to realise it? I've got just separate png files for my CCAnimation. I don't want to resize sprite's files physically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to change `scale` property of the sprite, that you use to run this animation. Sprite should resize all the frames of your animation automatically.

Comment: Fine! it works! self.sprite.scaleX=0.1; but why after this self.sprite.contentSize.width is the same?

Comment: contentSize is just a property. for sprite it is calculated automatically when you create it with file ot with spriteframe. but you can simply consider it's scale property, if you need it's displayed contentSize.